# Use of equation \(...\) versus \[...\] in latex documents

Tags: equations

I cannot understand when to use `\(...\)` versus `\[...\]`.  Are there general rules on which to use?

Comment: Inline math vs displayed math. Though most people use`$... $` instead of `\(... \) `. When using amsmath (recommended) `\[... \] ` is the same as `\begin{equationf}... \end{equation*} `

Comment: @dalief I take that they're asking not about the technical difference in what they do, but as a writer, when is it good practice to display your math, and when is it good practice to keep it inline? I don't think there are fixed rules, but if something is long or complicated, always use display math. If it's short and simple, then I'd still use display math if it's really important, at least when first introduced. But if it's just something minor that fits into the flow of the sentence, use inline.

Comment: Do both work with MathJax?

Comment: they do work with mathjax, although mathjax-specific questions are mostly off topic here.

Comment: Thank you.   Have used `\[... \]`, but can one include a label and equation number.  Or is that something to do with  `\begin{equation}  ...  \end{equation}`?

Comment: `\[... \]` does not introduce an equation number. If you want one, use `\begin{equation}  ...  \end{equation}` without the asterisk.